# How to iterate over temporary pairs

Tags: c++, for-loop, temporary

I would like to loop over an array of temporary pairs (with specifying as few types as possible)

```
for (const auto [x, y] : {{1, 1.0}, {2, 1.1}, {3, 1.2}}) {
  // ...
}
```

Is that possible? (I am free to use any C++ standard which is implemented in gcc 11.2)

Currently I am using a workaround using `map`s which is quite verbose

```
for (const auto [x, y] : std::map<int, double>{{1, 1.0}, {2, 1.1}, {3, 1.2}}) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to avoid specifying the types? Because `for (const auto [x, y] : std::initializer_list<std::pair<int,double>>{{1, 1.0}, {2, 1.1}, {3, 1.2}}) {` seems to do it.

Comment: @Borgleader "
I'm assuming you want to avoid specifying the types?" Yes, I clarified my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::map` performs a heap allocation, which is a bit wasteful. `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, double>>` is better in this regard, but more verbose.

A bit saner alternative:

```
for (const auto [x, y] : {std::pair{1, 1.0}, {2, 1.1}, {3, 1.2}})
```

Note that in this case the type of the first element dictates the types of the remaining elements. E.g. if you do `{std::pair{1, 2}, {3.1, 4.1}}`, the last pair becomes `{3,4}`, since the first one uses `int`s.

Answer (score 5):

As a minimal solution, you can iterate over a `std::initializer_list` of `std::pair`s by explicitly making at least one element of the initializer list a `std::pair`:

```
for (const auto [x, y] : {std::pair{1, 1.0}, {2, 1.1}, {3, 1.2}}) {
  // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/74asWe66c) on godbolt.